# Add class if url CONTAINS href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript (which works GREAT btw)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[href]").each(function() {
if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass("select");
    }
});
});
```

This works like a dream when the url is exactly the same. However, I want to check the parentage. For example, my href goes to "/DailyDeal.asp?deal=", so my class will only get added if that is the exact url. I want to add the class in a situation such as "/DailyDeal.asp?deal=62".

I think what I want to do is check to see if my current URL contains "/DailyDeal.asp?deal=", or something along those lines, I'm just a noob in JS and have no idea what the syntax is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be the safest bet:

```
$(function(){
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  if ( path.length > 1 ) {
    $('a[href*="' + path + '"]').addClass('select');
  }
});
```

Comment: I just made a small edit to it. I forgot to quote the attribute value. Let me know if that works.

Comment: i'm still not able to get this one. Like I said, I'm a noob w/ JS, do I need to ready the function or anything like that?

Comment: The suggestion `$('a[href*="' + window.location.pathname + '"]')` will not use query string, '?deal=', during match which also needs to be considered.

Comment: Yes, you need to ready it. I've edited it again. @NiteshKumarAnand I understand. Not sure there would be a neat solution to that, though. Curious to see if he OP can get away with this.

Comment: AWESOME!!! Thanks a bunch man! I've just familiarized myself w/ html/css and wanted to try and do some cool stuff w/ JS. Thanks again man!

Comment: It looks like if i'm on the homepage, that class is added (which makes sense). Is there a way to add an exception or say remove the class if url == blahblah.com?

Comment: I just made an edit to it so it would only fun if the path length is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the href that is the given url as so:

```
$("[href^='" + window.location.href   + "']").addClass("select");
```

This will match all hrefs that start with the current location. If you want it to contain the current page href you can use `"[href*='" + location.href + "']"`

Comment: Wow! fast response! I seem to be getting the same results as the function i've been using.

Comment: Try `*=` (contains) see http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors for other attribute selectors

Comment: I tried both of these and haven't had much success. I understand the *= concept (I didn't know this was the syntax), but when I update my file I'm not getting any new results